# Ionic2: Use chartjs inside ion-segment

Tags: angular, ionic2, chart.js

I am trying to place a chart inside `ion-segment`. When the page gets loaded for the first time, the canvas is displayed on the selected segment. But then when I click on other segments I am getting this error:

> Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined

I could see a blank html tag inside canvas and the actual chartjs iframe is not copied. I tried a lot of options but couldn't find a solution. Is there any other option to make this work? Please help

My ts code:

```
// On entering it works without issue as the element is now available
ionViewDidEnter(){
        let c = this.canvas.nativeElement;
        this.set1(c);            
    }
 //Switch case executes and error is thrown on any other segment is placed
 switch (level) {
            case "0":
                let c = this.canvas.nativeElement;
                this.set1(c); 
                break;
            case "1":
                let c1 = this.canvas1.nativeElement;
                this.set2(c1);
                break;
            case "2":
                let c2 = this.canvas2.nativeElement;
                this.set3(c2);
                break;
        }
```

My HTML:

```
<div *ngSwitchCase="'easy'">
      <canvas #canvas></canvas>
</div>
<div *ngSwitchCase="'medium'">
     <canvas #canvas1></canvas>
</div>
<div *ngSwitchCase="'hard'">
     <canvas #canvas2></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Is the switch in a function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem with chart.js in `ion-segment` and solved it by using the `[hidden]` directive, e.g.

```
 <canvas #canvas1 [hidden]="selectedValue!=1"></canvas>
 <canvas #canvas2 [hidden]="selectedValue!=2"></canvas>
 <canvas #canvas3 [hidden]="selectedValue!=3"></canvas>
```